# Displaying all items which have been backordered within an order?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, backorder

Using Magento EE 1.9, I've enabled backorders, but there's no way to see if an order contains backordered items in the Sales/Orders grid view.

How would I check if an item was backordered or not after an order has been placed?

(Code-based solutions are fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
    $items = array();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        $sumBackordered = 0;
        $children = array();

        if ($orderItem->getHasChildren()) {
            foreach ($orderItem->getChildrenItems() as $childItem) {
                $sumBackordered += (float)$childItem->getQtyBackordered();
                $children[] = array(
                    'name'              => $childItem->getName(),
                    'qty_backordered'   => (float)$childItem->getQtyBackordered()
                );
            }
        }

        $items[] = array(
            'name'              => $orderItem->getName(),
            'qty_backordered'   => $orderItem->getHasChildren() ? $sumBackordered : (float)$orderItem->getQtyBackordered(),
            'children'          => $orderItem->getHasChildren() ? $children : null
        );
    }

    Zend_Debug::dump($items);
```