# Check if order line/item was backordered

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, backorder

I'm checking each order line.

If the line was ordered, I have to do to something. If it was backordered, I will have to do something different. Like this:

```
private function myFunction($order){
    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach($orderItems as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        if( $item was ordered )
            foo();
        elseif( $item was backordered ) 
            bar();

    }

}
```

I've already tried this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49684/displaying-all-items-which-have-been-backordered-within-an-order) but it doesn't work.

How can I check both scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Below code

Assuming `$_product` is your product object.

```
    <?php $product_inventory = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product) ?>
    <?php if($product_inventory->getBackorders() == 1 || $product_inventory->getBackorders() == 2): ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Back Ordered') endif; ?>
```

You can also refer to this solution for [More Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419558/how-to-get-backorder-status-from-product-information-programmatically-in-magento)

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: Doesn't work. The solution must be based on order to know if the product was backorder when the order was placed.